# Div appears beyond parent div on slideToggle

Tags: jquery, html, slidetoggle

I have created a div such that the when the mouseenter is triggered, another div must get viewed and this is achieved with slideToggle. Now my problem is that the div which must toggle appears partially outside the page towards the right and is not visible unless the user scrolls right. How can I prevent this? I want the div the appear in the next line and don't want the page to expand sideways as that breaks the experience.

EDIT: The page works fine in most conditions but exhibits this on chrome + wide screens

You can see this [here](http://www.offcampus.in) on hovering over the images on the orange div ater the first page down

Comment: Any chance you can create a fiddle with this; I'm having a hard time picturing the issue? jsfiddle.net

Comment: even better, shall I give you the link to the website where this happens?

Comment: That would work for me.

Comment: Have added the link in the edit. You will have a scroll down to the orange section to see this.

Comment: Try changing the "Find Resources" icon to 128px by 128px like the other 3. I did it in dev tools (Chrome, large), and it seems to have corrected the issue. When I resized large the image became larger too.

Comment: Hey that worked. Thanks a lot. But how did you figure that was the issue and why was it causing trouble?

Comment: Just figured something was pushing it out of focus, and the image was the only thing resizing. Neat to see things change on a live site per suggestions on here. Now to diagnose the green section which is doing the same thing with only 3 images...

Comment: I'll check it out right away. And just fyi, I have built this and one more website just with the support from stackoverflow. I can never be thankful enough to this great community.

Comment: Looks like you have to add "clear:both;" as a style property to the description DIVs to stop them from thinking the elements before them are floating left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to have an answer here instead of solely comments. The issue was related to the float attribute (actually not the image that resizes). The items before your descriptions are set to float left, so the descriptions think that when there's enough space, they should sit to the right of the floated elements. So for this, for each of your description DIVs that comes after a register button, you should add the CSS attribute:

```
clear:both;
```

Comment: I was unaware of this property. Thanks a lot Mark